# Upload a file - special characters are converted to html chars?

Tags: java, html, gwt, serialization, file-upload

I want to read a file using file chose dialog and send it to the server.
Therefore on the client side I created a form that has the content of the file as a String in the `SubmitCompleteEvent`.

Problem: already on the client side (before sending the content to the server), special characters like `&` are incorrectly read as eg `&amp;`, so somehow replaced with the `HTML` character implementation.

Question: Why, and more important: how can I prevent this? If I can't prevent this, this would mean I'd have to run a regex against all special characters the could occure in a file, and replace their html representation. That would be kind of senseless...

```
 @UiField FormPanel uploadForm;

 @UiHandler("uploadForm")
    void onSubmitForm(SubmitCompleteEvent evt) {  
    Sysout(evt.getResults()); //prints: &amp;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround to convert the input on the serverside to UTF-8 by:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(input);
```